# The entity type 'AspNetUserLogins' requires a primary key to be defined?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, identity

I scaffolded my database with EF and I changed the `mydbcontext` to inherit from `IdentityDbContext` because I want everything under one `dbcontext`.

The problem is that when I start the application and write the credentials in the login page, I get an exception:

> The entity type 'AspNetUserLogins' requires a primary key to be defined

which I didn't get before, because I am calling the `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class AdventuresContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> 
{
    public AdventuresContext()
    {
    }

    public AdventuresContext(DbContextOptions<AdventuresContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Adventures> Adventures { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Adventures");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.4-servicing-10062");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Adventures>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId);

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryCodeIso03from).HasColumnName("CountryCodeISO03From");

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryCodeIso03to).HasColumnName("CountryCodeISO03To");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.ShortDescription).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.Property(e => e.Timestamp).IsRowVersion();

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).IsRequired();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.Adventures)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Adventures_Adventures");
        });
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `IdentityDbContext` has primary key of type `GUID` but your models have primary key of type `integer`. so EF cannot find a proper primary key for your models.

Comment: It should have 2 primary keys of type string: LoginProvider and ProviderKey In database they appear as nvarchar(450) and in my model they are strings. All was done automatically by EF.

Comment: @user3777245 did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways to fix this.

You could add the [Key] on a public property in your AspNetUserLogins class with a getter and setter, for example:

```
[Key]
public int SomeFieldName {get;set;}
```

Or you could use your OnModelCreating override to call HasNoKey(), for example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
    .Entity<AspNetUserLogins>(o =>
    {
        o.HasNoKey();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The AspNetUsersLogins is the standard class that comes with Identity. It has 2 primary keys, which are  LoginProvider and ProviderKey. I tried to change them from string to Guid but still the same message. I also tried to put on both of them the [Key] attribue and i have an exception that says: "InvalidOperationException: Entity type 'AspNetUserLogins' has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API.". Any other ideas?The AspNetUsersLogins that EF scaffolded looks like this:

```
public partial class AspNetUserLogins
{

    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public string ProviderDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUsers User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to use fluent api to add composite key:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys#fluent-api

Comment: Yes i need fluent Api, but still I don't understand why i have to define any primary key myself since i am inheriting from IdentityDbContext and calling the base OnModelCreating method. The primary keys shoud be by default. I don't have anything custom. Maybe there is a mismatch between my model and the types but EF Scaffolding created myAspNetUserLogins model out of the database Automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you inherit from `IdentityDbContext`, there is no need for you to recreate `AspNet*` DbSet,I suggest you remove all the built-in `DbSet<AspNet*>`  and `modelBuilder.Entity<AspNet*>.`

```
public partial class AdventuresContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AdventuresContext ()
    {
    }

    public AdventuresContext (DbContextOptions<AdventuresContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Adventures> Adventures { get; set; }
    //remove below DbSet
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Adventures");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //...
    } 
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        var conn = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Adventures";
        services.AddDbContext<AdventuresContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(conn));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AdventuresContext>();
    }
```

Comment: You are right thank you, but still doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @user3777245 What 's the error now after removing those `DbSet`?

Comment: Is the same like before "The entity type 'AspNetUserLogins' requires a primary key to be defined."

Comment: @user3777245 I could not reproduce that. I use db first to an Identity database and use above settings.