# ASP.NET Core MVC error - The entity type 'AspNetUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using `Identity` in my ASP.NET Core MVC project. Except that, I have 2 more models, that I need to join with `Id` in `AspNetUsers` table. So, I used 3 migrations, 1 is `Add-Migration AddAuthentication` and 2 more for models. Then, by using `Scaffold-DbContext` I made models from database. And here is the problem, after that, I am getting this error:

```
The entity type 'AspNetUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

I used to get that error in my project after login, but then, as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461666/the-entity-type-aspnetuserlogins-requires-a-primary-key-to-be-defined) I just removed those getters and setters. Didn't work. And here is my last try, I tried to create that column manually, but now, I am getting this error while `Update-Database`.

Here is changed part of automatic created migration - there was no `Id` column:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "AspNetUserLogins",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
        LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
        ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
        ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
        UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
            column: x => x.UserId,
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

I absolutely have no idea what's wrong. Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461666/the-entity-type-aspnetuserlogins-requires-a-primary-key-to-be-defined) was quite right. After migrations and creating tables, I have done `Scaffold-DbContext` and got models in other, temporary folder. Then, I just copied it in `Models` folder, **but**, I have changed context a little bit. I removed all ASP staff and kept only my tables. So now, it looks like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

#nullable disable

namespace Project.Models
{
    public partial class WebBankDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public WebBankDbContext()
        {

        }
        public WebBankDbContext(DbContextOptions<WebBankDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=WebBank;Trusted_Connection=True");
            }
        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT** In automatic created authentication migrations I had to add id's for a couple of tables, to avoid that `the entity type 'AspNetUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined` error.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a relation and adding new columns to AspNetUsers entity you have to define and extra class which must be inherited from IdentityUser. Here is the example

```
public class AspNetUserLogins

{

[Key]
public Guid Id {get; set;}

public Guid UserId {get; set;}

public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
        {
            public ApplicationUser()
            {
                aspNetUserLogins = new List<AspNetUserLogins>();
    
            }
            public bool IsActive { get; set; }
            public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
            public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogins> aspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        }
```

On the context class you must set like this.

```
 public class YourDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
    {
        public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
}
```

This is I think good approach to modify Identity table.